# Getting data from react state function component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, state

I have 2 function component , one have input and button and its passing data to states. Now i want to get state data from first function conlmponent  to second component and display text to my div in second component. Is it possible to share states data from 1st component to 2nd component?
The component are functions not classes

```
function Articles(){
  return(<div>
    <h1>{inputtext}</h1>
  </div>)
}

function Inputform() {
  const [inputtext, setInputtext] = useState('');
  const [task_list,setTask_list] = useState([]);

  function changer(event){
    setInputtext(event.target.value);
  }
  function add_post(){
    setTask_list(inputtext);
  }

  return (
    <div>
    <label>Post</label>
    <input name="first" onChange={changer} />
    <button onClick={add_post}>Dodaj</button>
    </div>
  )
}
```

trying to get states in Articles from Input but it doesnt work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

what you would like to do, is to put this two components inside a third one and have them share whatever states/data you want.

```
function ThirdComponent() {
    const [inputtext, setInputtext] = useState('');
    const [task_list,setTask_list] = useState([]);

    function Articles(){
      return(<div>
       <h1>{inputtext}</h1>
      </div>)
    }
    function Inputform() {
      
      function changer(event){
        setInputtext(event.target.value);
      }
      function add_post(){
        setTask_list(inputtext);
      }

      return (
        <div>
           <label>Post</label>
           <input name="first" onChange={changer} />
           <button onClick={add_post}>Dodaj</button>
        </div>
     )
    }
    return (
        <>
        </>
    ) 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

State belongs to a component. It does not create global variables.

If you want to pass data from a state to another component, then:

- The recipient must be a child of the element holding the data
- You can pass it as a *prop*

Since you don't have `<Article propName={stateVariable} />` you can't do that.

---

If the destination isn't a child of the element holding the state then you need to [Lift State Up](https://reactjs.org/tutorial/tutorial.html#lifting-state-up).

1. Move the `useState` hook to component that is ancestor of both `<Article>` and `<Inputform>`
2. Pass the `set` function as a prop to `<Inputform>`
3. Pass the state value variable as a prop to `<Article>`.

---

For complex systems where the common ancestor is a long way from the components that need to work with the state, you might consider using [Context](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html) or an external state management system like [Redux](https://react-redux.js.org/).